# How to find and delete a certain number of rows with the same consecutive value in a column in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

In my dataframe there is a column with "Sound" and "Response" as values. Ideally, the pattern is two Sounds followed by one Response. But, it can happen that there are three Sounds followed by a Response.

How can I tell R to raise a flag whenever it finds this pattern in my data? I need to look at each case individually before I can delete the third Sound-row.

```
>df <- data.frame(V1=rep("SN", 7),  
             V3=c("Sound", "Sound", "Response", "Sound", "Sound", "Sound", "Response"), 
             V4=c("XYZc02i03", "XYZq02i03", 200, "ZYXc01i30", "ZYXq01i30", "ZYXc01i35", 100), 
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 

V1       V3        V4
SN    Sound XYZc02i03
SN    Sound XYZq02i03
SN Response       200
SN    Sound ZYXc01i30
SN    Sound ZYXq01i30
SN    Sound ZYXc01i35
SN Response       100
```

So, after finding three consecutive Sounds and deleting the last one of them (i. e. the one just before the folowing Response), I should have the desired pattern like this:

```
V1       V3        V4
SN    Sound XYZc02i03
SN    Sound XYZq02i03
SN Response       200
SN    Sound ZYXc01i30
SN    Sound ZYXq01i30
SN Response       100
```

I'm sorry that I keep posting these basic questions. Any ideas are, as always, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cumsum(rle(df$V3)$lengths)[rle(df$V3)$lengths == 3]
[1] 6
```

this returns the vector of positions where "Sound" is third in a row. Now you can easily delete them or make some column to mark these positions.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work, although there are probably much simpler solutions:

```
df <- data.frame(V1=rep("SN", 7),  
             V3=c("Sound", "Sound", "Response", "Sound", "Sound", "Sound", "Response"), 
             V4=c("XYZc02i03", "XYZq02i03", 200, "ZYXc01i30", "ZYXq01i30", "ZYXc01i35", 100), 
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df

my.run <- rep(0,dim(df)[1])

if(df$V3[1]=='Sound') (my.run[1] = 1) else my.run[1] = 0

for (i in 2:dim(df)[1]) {

     if(df$V3[i]=='Sound') (my.run[i] = my.run[i-1] + 1) else my.run[i] = 0

}

df2 <- df[my.run < 3,]
df2
```

Comment: thanks mark, I was gonna accept your answer as well, but i guess i can only accept 1 answer. So i used your code as well, as i could easily adjust it to detect some other patterns in my data  that i was going to throw out, too.